# How to create a variant of "\leadsto" symbol with bigger arrow tip?

Tags: symbols

I want to create a variant of the "\leadsto" (`$\leadsto$`) symbol with bigger arrow tip, for example, like the arrow tip of `$\Leftarrow$`.

I tried to look at a comprehensive list of Latex symbols but could not find any symbol which is close to what I want.

Does anybody know how to make that kind of symbol?

---

**Update 1:**

My MWE is as follow:

```
% pdflatex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}
  $\leadsto \Rightarrow \hookrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows]

I'm trying to make the arrow tip of `$\leadsto$` as big as those of `$\Rightarrow \hookrightarrow$`, but haven't been able to do it yet.

I have another question is that: *Does Latex provide separate arrow tip symbols?*

Answer (score 3):

Well, those are font decisions so at first, I would decide which font you want to use. Here are some examples:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\renewcommand{\leadsto}{\rightsquigarrow}

\begin{document}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}% this is default
$\leadsto\rightarrow\Rightarrow$ 

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
$\leadsto\rightarrow\Rightarrow$ 

\setmathfont{STIX Math}
$\leadsto\rightarrow\Rightarrow$ 

\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
$\leadsto\rightarrow\Rightarrow$ 

\setmathfont{Asana Math}
$\leadsto\rightarrow\Rightarrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe there is something that fits and you do not have to design your own symbol.

But in order to really help you, you will have to give us an MWE which shows your setup. I am guessing that it looks like this for you:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\leadsto\rightsquigarrow\rightarrow\Rightarrow$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also `$\leadsto$` from the package `latexsym` but that is not what you want, I fear.

You could also check http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%87%9D+-+Unicode+Character+%27RIGHTWARDS+SQUIGGLE+ARROW%27+%28U%2B21DD%29 in order to see, which fonts on your system do provide this symbol.

Comment: Thanks for your careful reply! I have updated my question in the original post with a MWE. My problem seems relating to your second answer and I have not been able to resolve it. I wonder if Latex provide separate arrow tip symbols?